# How do I fix suspend in HP Chromebook 14? (Chrubuntu 14.10)

Tags: 14.10, suspend, laptop, hp, chrubuntu

WHen I close the lid, it suspends, but when I open it again, the screen stays full black. If I hit the power button, occasionally it will come back to life but sometimes i have to force a reboot unfortunately.

Comment: What are you actually suspending? Chrome OS or the chrooted Ubuntu environment? This would be similar to asking why a VM acts erratic during suspend and resume of the host. You are not running a supported installation of Ubuntu when you run Chrubuntu or crouton.

Comment: I don't use Crouton or the host OS. I think you are confusing Crouton and Chrubuntu.

Chrubuntu is a seperate partition that boots via SeaLion which in turn boots grub and is the full blown Linux kernal running ubuntu with it's own drivers and everything. It has no memory sharing with ChromeOS, like Crouton does.

Comment: No offense, I'm quite happy to be proven wrong by you. It has not gotten to my attention that there was such a script that does that. I was always searching for a project site and only found one for crouton, apparently there is only a blog http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.de/2013/10/chrubuntu-for-new-chromebooks-now-with.html to add to the confusion there is another one that also advertises crouton http://chrubuntu.blogspot.ca/ **vote to close retracted**

Comment: It's very confusing, I admit. To learn more about Chrubuntu, check out the resources at the bottom of the readme here: https://github.com/eyecreate/ubuntu-chromebook-installer

Comment: I just found this in one of the links: http://realityequation.net/installing-elementary-os-on-an-hp-chromebook-14
*"Step 4: Solve issue with suspend"* Have you checked that?

Comment: ^ I Hear that was the official way to do it, but someone found a 'newer way' since. I just posted the asnwer below. THanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

All thanks to linvinus on reddit: [How to make hibernate working in ubuntu 14.04 on Acer c720](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1rsxkd/list_of_fixes_for_xubuntu_1310_on_the_acer_c720/ch8eq2o)

How to make hibernate working in ubuntu 14.04 on Acer c720, tested in HP Chromebook 14 on Ubuntu 14.10 kernel 3.17 as well, works. He has Lubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.13.0-24-generic c720 2G. For Debian, Arch, or Xubuntu, there are more instructions in the source link.

Takes about 5 mins to do, but works like a charm for me,

> 1. create file
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/unbind_ehci
>    ```
>
>    with following content
>
>    ```
>    #####################
>    #!/bin/sh
>    PREREQ=""
>
>    prereqs()
>    {
>            echo "${PREREQ}"
>    }
>
>    case ${1} in
>            prereqs)
>                    prereqs
>                    exit 0
>                    ;;
>    esac
>
>    log_success_msg "Unbind ehci for preventing error"
>    echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
>    exit 0
>    #################
>    ```
>
>    change mode
>
>    ```
>    sudo chmod a+x /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/unbind_ehci
>    ```
> 2. create udev rule
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10_disable-ehci.rules
>
>    ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", DRIVER=="ehci_hcd", \
>        RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k > %S%p/driver/unbind'"
>    ```
> 3. update initramfs
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
>    ```
> 4. this script will fix touchpad after resume
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/99zcyapa
>    ```
>
>    with following content
>
>    ```
>    #####################
>    #!/bin/bash -x
>    # File: "/etc/pm/sleep.d/99_cyapa".
>    case "${1}" in
>            hibernate)
>          /sbin/rmmod cyapa
>                    ;;
>      resume|thaw)
>              COUNTER=0
>              while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
>                            date >>/tmp/99_cyapa
>                            /sbin/modprobe cyapa
>              sleep 1
>              dmesg | grep cyapa | tail -1 | grep error >/dev/null
>              RES=$?
>              echo "res=$RES"
>              if [ ${RES} -ne 1 ] ; then
>                  /sbin/rmmod cyapa
>                  sleep 1
>              else
>                  #done
>                  COUNTER=11
>              fi
>
>                      COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
>              done
>          ;;
>    esac
>    exit 0
>    #################
>    ```
>
>    Change mode!
>
>    ```
>    sudo chmod a+x /etc/pm/sleep.d/99zcyapa
>    ```
> 5. ensure that in you have `tpm_tis.interrupts=0`
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/default/grub
>    ```
>
>    there is my settings
>
>    ```
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash  boot=local  i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 "
>    ```
>
>    update grub
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-grub2
>    ```
>
>    Reboot

Again thanks to linvinus on reddit